# Programmatically rotate monitor

Tags: python, winapi

I'm working on making a utility script that does a whole bunch of things.  One of the things I want to do is to rotate a display; I have multiple monitors, and I want the main one to rotate.  I know this sort of thing usually works through `win32api` and I found a few functions there that seem helpful, but I'm struggling with the implementation.

*Everything between this line and the next is out of date, see below second line for up to date description of solution attempts*

---

After burying my face in the docs, I'm afraid I still don't have much of an idea on how to move forward aside from that it will likely involve `win32api.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()`.  I know I need to give that function a pointer to a `DEVMODE` object (not even sure how to do C pointers in python), which I think I can get from `win32api.EnumDisplaySettingsEx()`.   So if I try,

```
>>> import win32api as win32
>>> a = win32.EnumDisplayDevices()
>>> type(a)
```

I should get something that involves `DEVMODE` pointer or whatever, but instead I get

```
>>> type(a)
<type 'PyDISPLAY_DEVICE'>
```

And I have no idea what to do with that, but I think [this is the structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932948.aspx)

So, how do I get a `DEVMODE` ojbect I can give to `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()` so that I can rotate one of my displays?  Thanks in advance.

I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows 7

**EDIT:**  If I acutally use the correct function, it still doesn't work.  Could this be the Python module be not complete?

```
>>> a = win32.EnumDisplaySettings()
>>> type(a)
<type 'PyDEVMODEA'>
>>> a.dmSize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'PyDEVMODEA' object has no attribute 'dmSize'
>>> a.dmScale
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'PyDEVMODEA' object has no attribute 'dmScale'
>>> a.dmDisplayOrientation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'PyDEVMODEA' object has no attribute 'dmDisplayOrientation'
```

Now, I noticed that this is giving me a `DEVMODEA` object instead of `DEVMODE`, but [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942189.aspx) says they're the same.  What could be the issue here?

**EDIT:** Now that I'm using the correct attribute names, I can get a valid `DEVMODEA` object:

```
>>> a = win32.EnumDisplaySettings()
>>> a.Size
124L
>>> a.DisplayOrientation
0L
```

And change the orientation in the object:

```
>>> a.DisplayOrientation = 90L
>>> a.DisplayOrientation
90L
```

I can then attempt to "apply" these changes by giving this `DEVMODEA` object to `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()`

```
>>> win32.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(a.DeviceName, a, 0)
-5L
```

<strike>This does nothing.  Unfortnately, [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923082.aspx) aren't very useful in helping me interpret the return value.  I'm assuming `-5L` is some sort of error code since it didn't work, but I have no way of knowing which one.  What does this return value mean and how do I get my new `DEVMODEA` object to "apply"</strike>

I've worked out that `-5L` return value indicates a bad parameter.  Specifically, its angry at the first field.  If I replace that with `DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName`, I get a `-2L` result.  This corresponds to a bad mode (whatever that is).  This happens even if I give `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()` exactly what `EnumDisplaySettings()` puts out.

---

So my progress so far:

```
>>> import win32api as win32
>>> import win32con
>>> a = win32.EnumDisplaySettings()
>>> a.DisplayOrientation
0L
>>> a.DisplayOrientation = win32con.DMDO_90
>>> a.DisplayOrientation
1L
>>> a.PelsWidth, a.PelsHeight = a.PelsHeight, a.PelsWidth
>>> a.Fields = a.Fields & win32con.DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION
>>> name = win32.EnumDisplayDevices().DeviceName
>>> name
'\\\\.\\DISPLAY1'
>>> win32.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(name, a)
-2L
```

---

Most recent attempt (6/4, 10:50am EST)

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import win32api as win32
>>> import win32con
>>>
>>> device = win32.EnumDisplayDevices(None, 1)
>>> print "Rotate device {} ({})".format(device.DeviceString, device.DeviceName)
Rotate device Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (\\.\DISPLAY2)
>>>
>>> dm = win32.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, win32con.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pywintypes.error: (0, 'EnumDisplaySettings', 'No error message is available')
>>>
>>> dm = win32.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pywintypes.error: (123, 'EnumDisplaySettings', 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.')
>>>
>>> dm = win32.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, win32con.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pywintypes.error: (123, 'EnumDisplaySettings', 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.')
>>>
```

Notice how the first and third attempt to create `dm` fail *with different errors despite being the same code*.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Comment: Isn't that what the ```win32api``` module is supposed to do?

Comment: The documentation states, that `EnumDisplaySettings()` returns your expected `DEVMODE`. However, in your sample code, you call `EnumDisplayDevices()`, which is a different function. The latter is correctly returning `DISPLAY_DEVICE`.

I shortly observed the source of PyWin32 and `EnumDisplaySettings()` seems to be available.

Unfortunately I haven't tested it yet, but I am sure that it's going to work.

Comment: You need a monitor with a motorized rotation and a suitable API to control it. Or maybe you just want to rotate the display :)

Comment: Did you see `The following table shows the values in the dmFields member that you must also set to change the display settings, in addition to using one or more of the preceding DEVMODE members.`?

Comment: @Bengt, yes, but how do I access those constants?  ```win32api.DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION``` throws an ```AttributeError```

Answer (score 11):

You are calling the `EnumDisplayDevices` API that returns a PDISPLAY_DEVICE.
(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can obtain the object in two way:

1) From EnumDisplayDevicesEx

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.EnumDisplaySettingsEx()
<PyDEVMODEA object at 0x00512E78>
```

2) or creating it (it will be empty)

```
>>> import pywintypes;
>>> dmode = pywintypes.DEVMODEType()
>>> type(dmode)
<type 'PyDEVMODEA'>
```

**EDIT:**

the property exposed by the object are **not** named like the "win32" version: for example `dmSize` becomes `Size` the full list can be seen with `dir(dmode)` command on `PyDEVMODEA` object.

The description of the fields can be read with the `help(dmode)` command on a `PyDEVMODEA` object.

For a full detailed mapping refer to `PyDEVMODE.cpp` inside the pywin32 source distribution

**EDIT2:**
The procedure to rotate the monitor is:

1. Get Devmode
2. Get DisplayName
3. Set Rotation
4. Configure the flags with a.Fields = a.Fields & win32con.DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION
5. Invoke ChangeDisplaySettingsEx

In your script you are missing steps from 3-5. (also Fields is used as a binary mask so must handled corrispondly).

You can see a complete example about the api usage (in C) on the msdn site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx

**Edit3**
During "Set Rotation" you must also need to swap width and height, otherwise you are asking an screen mode that is not possible:

```
(dmode.PelsWidth,dmode.PelsHeight) = (dmode.PelsHeight,dmode.PelsWidth)
```

**EDIT4**
A complete example (with no error checking):

```
import win32api as win32
import win32con

def printAllScreen():
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            device = win32.EnumDisplayDevices(None,i);
            print("[%d] %s (%s)"%(i,device.DeviceString,device.DeviceName));
            i = i+1;
        except:
            break;
    return i

screen_count=printAllScreen()
x = int(input("\nEnter a display number [0-%d]: "%screen_count-1))


device = win32.EnumDisplayDevices(None,x);
print("Rotate device %s (%s)"%(device.DeviceString,device.DeviceName));

dm = win32.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName,win32con.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS)
dm.DisplayOrientation = win32con.DMDO_90
dm.PelsWidth, dm.PelsHeight = dm.PelsHeight, dm.PelsWidth
dm.Fields = dm.Fields & win32con.DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION
win32.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(device.DeviceName,dm)
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far! Almost there, made another edit

Comment: I'm getting ```pywintypes.error: (0, 'EnumDisplaySettings', 'No error message is available')```, is this a Python 3 v 2 difference? (It looks like you're on 3 and I'm on 2)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a bit hacky but it works. It is based on the fact that the screen rotates when the special combination of keys is pressed by the user.

```
from win32api import keybd_event

def rotate_screen(orientation):
    vals = dict(zip(['left', 'up', 'right', 'down'],
                    [37, 38, 39, 40])) 
    comb = 165, vals[orientation]
    for k in comb:
        keybd_event(k, 0, 1, 0)
    for k in reversed(comb):
        keybd_event(k, 0, 2, 0)
```

Example:

```
rotate_screen('down')
```

Note: Ibenini's approach is obviously better because it is more reliable. I posted this method only as an example of a simpler way of doing that.

Comment: There are much better ways to approach this problem.
As always, auto-typing keyboard shortcuts is unreliable.

Comment: Well, you have just repeated the note at the end of the answer :)